# Create custom roles mvc3

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

i am creating a MVC3 application where the user can be either an Admin or a Data Entry, so i need to make use of the Role in user authentication that MVC offers. So in my Register Form I Have added

```
                    <%=  
                           Html.DropDownList("RoleName", new SelectListItem[]{ 
                           new SelectListItem{ Text= "Admin", Value="admin"},
                           new SelectListItem{ Text= "Data Entry", Value="data"}
                    }) %>
```

And i modified the register controller as follows:

```
if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
                {
                    Roles.AddUserToRole(model.UserName, "RoleName");
                    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false /* createPersistentCookie */);
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
```

Now when i register i get the following error:
The role '' was not found.

Thank you ...

Comment: Because you don't have a role called "RoleName". You need to write your method to fetch the roles in your dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the definition for `Roles.AddUserToRole()` method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx).  You are hardcoding "RoleName" for the second parameter which is supposed the role to add the user to.

What you want to do is retrieve the selected value from your `DropDownList` and use that string in your `Roles.AddUserToRole()` method call.

Comment: yeah this is what i was doing wrong i was assuming the roleName as the name of the dropdown list without parsing it as string at first ...